# Bluetooth 4.0 and transfer speeds of USB dongles

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth

I have a general question about hardware here, specifically Bluetooth 4.0. I've been looking to upgrade my little Bluetooth USB dongle from an earlier version (I think it's ~2.1) to something newer, but the speeds listed for Bluetooth 4.0 do not make sense on NewEgg / vendor sites.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth

```
Version     Data rate   Maximum application throughput
Version 1.2     1 Mbit/s    0.7 Mbit/s
Version 2.0 + EDR   3 Mbit/s    2.1 Mbit/s
Version 3.0 + HS    24 Mbit/s   See Version 3.0+HS.
Version 4.0     See Version 4.0LE.
```

Now, I could be wrong, but I am seeing 4.0 devices listed with 3 MBit/s maximum speeds. Assuming backwards compatibility with previous editions, the maximum speed should be at least 24 Mbit/s.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320166

```
Interface
    USB 2.0

Bluetooth Standards
    Bluetooth 4.0

Transfer rate
    Up to 3.0Mbps
```

I normally enjoy Asus stuff, and have included the above as an example.

Am I just looking at the wrong products? Is there something about the spec I do not understand? Am I reading it incorrectly? Anyone have any idea what's going on here? I don't think it's a limitation of USB 2.0...

Answer (score -2):

The improvements on bluetooth from 2.0 to 4.0 are mainly optional characteristics such as Enhanced Data Rate (EDR) for 2.0 -> High speed (HS) for 3.0 (this takes advantages of lower frequencies like 802.11 and makes the transfer speed go up to 24Mbits/s) -> and finally Low Energy for 4.0
These technologies do not enhance theoretically the transfer speed, and from what information you have given us, I must tell you: you simply swop between Mbytes (with a big B, this means 8bits) and Mbits
So when you're saying that 4.0 devices are listed as 3MBits/s, you're confusing yourself, it's 3MBytes/s which means 3*8: 24Mbits/s. There comes the confusion, don't worry, they did not intentionally drop down the transfer speed... 
Reference/source: see this article and the articles connected https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Bluetooth-4-0-3-0-and-2-0